# How to use AngularJS in .php file while rendering a laravel view

Tags: php, html, angularjs, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and AngularJS . I am trying to render a view which is a php file. The .php file is being rendered but the AngularJS expression inside it is not being evaluated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">     </script>
<script src='public/AngularSorter.js'></script>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"> </script>
</head>



<body ng-app = 'store'>
<div ng-controller ='SorterController as sorter'>
 <p>
   {{ 4+4 }}

 </p>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

the route is like this

```
Route::get('/', function () {
 return view('Home');
  });
```

Am I missing something? I tried renaming the php file to .html but it doesn't work. why  can't the view render .html file??.

I get the output as {{4+4}} instead of 8.

Comment: If you view source on the page, does it still say {{ 4+4 }}, does it say 8, or does it say nothing? Laravel blade and angularjs use the same syntax, so you'd have to change one of the two.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you picked an answer when you've got your problem solved. If you need more assistance to understand the answer, let me know! I'm here to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel Blade and AngularJS use the same syntax for processing variables, {}. To avoid this, you have to either change the syntax for blade or change the syntax for AngularJS. [Details here.](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/quick-tip-using-laravel-blade-with-angularjs)

**Changing the AngularJS Syntax**:

```
  var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});
```

***- or -***

**Changing the Laravel Blade Syntax:**

```
// You may place this code anywhere it is executed each request. Some people have used routes.php
Blade::setContentTags('<%', '%>');        // for variables and all things Blade
Blade::setEscapedContentTags('<%%', '%%>');   // for escaped data
```

Also, the view will need to be .blade.php, not .html. This is the standard for all laravel blade (view) files. Documentation here: http://laravel.com/docs/master/blade

Comment: I tried your trick but the output is still the same that is "{{4+4}}.

Comment: Would you be willing to provide a web link to the page? I could probably debug it pretty quickly if I could read the JS console and see the code.

Comment: Hi @Mikel Bitson I solved the issue by reordering the <script> tags . I had placed the angular.js at the end after the custom js files . I reordered it and placed it at the beginning.

Comment: @Adil That's great! Glad you've got the solution. I'd take heed and still change one or the other's syntax, they will conflict going forward.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by reordering the script tags. the Angular script tag should be placed at the beginning and then the self written javascript files should be included.